# GetListItems Exception

Tags: powershell, web-services

I am trying to get the contents of a Sharepoint 2007 list using Powershell.    I'm able to connect to the web service but receive an exception whenever I try to call the GetListItems method.

```
# Create credential object
$username = "domain\user"
$password = cat C:\users\user\dashboard\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

# Connect to web service
$uri = "https://sharepoint.com/teams/SysAdmin/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri –Credential $credential
$listname = 'Services'

$service.GetListItems($listname, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null)
```

> Exception calling "GetListItems" with "7" argument(s): "Exception of
>   type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerExcept ion' was
>   thrown." At C:\Users\user\Dashboard\sharepoint.ps1:15 char:22
>   + $service.GetListItems <<<< ($listname, "", $query, $viewFields, "", $queryOptions, "")
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out.   I had to connect to the parent Sharepoint site when creating the service object.   Then I specified the subsite web services address prior to calling GetListItems.

```
# Connect to web service
$uri = "https://sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri –Credential $credential

# Set service url to subsite
$service.url = "https://sharepoint.com/teams/SysAdmin/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"

# Pull contents of list
$listname = 'Services'
$list = $service.GetListItems($listname, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid this by just putting `?WSDL` on the end of the subset service URL and not change the url of the WebServiceProxy